# how to use amqp StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor

Tags: amqp, spring-amqp

I try to use StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor in mycode like that:

```
@Bean
public StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor statefulRetryOperationsInterceptor(){
   return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful()
          .maxAttempts(5)
          .backOffOptions(1000,2.0,10000)
          .build();
}

 @Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    logger.info("==> custom rabbitmq Listener factory:"+ connectionFactory);
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
    factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    factory.setPrefetchCount(200);
    factory.setAdviceChan(new Advice[]{
       statefulRetryOperationsInterceptor()
    })  //add retry
    return factory;
}
```

my code run well but when there is exception in consumer there are no retry at all.
so how to use the StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor? is that class used to catch exception and do the resend?

And if Exception happaned I want to requeue the message and resend to the consumer for 5 times, then send the message to dead queue, how to use amqp more elegant?

---

according to @Gary Russell's answer ,I use redis to record exceptions, Is there any method like StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor to do that more elegant?

```
try {
     receiveMessage(message);
    channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);           
    redisTemplate.opsForHash().delete(MQConstants.MQ_CONSUMER_RETRY_COUNT_KEY, messageProperties.getMessageId());
        } 
 catch (Exception e) {     
            if (consumerCount >= MQConstants.MAX_CONSUMER_COUNT) {         
                channel.basicReject(deliveryTag, false);
            } else {
               redisTemplate.opsForHash().increment(MQConstants.MQ_CONSUMER_RETRY_COUNT_KEY,
                        messageProperties.getMessageId(), 1);
                Thread.sleep((long) (Math.pow(MQConstants.BASE_NUM, consumerCount)*1000));
                channel.basicNack(deliveryTag, false, true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);`

Since you are using manual acks - you are on your own; the container can't help you. You need to use AUTO with stateful retry or use `channel.basicReject()` to requeue.

Comment: I use redis to record exceptions, Is there any method like StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor to do that?
 ` try{
}
`

Comment: You should really ask a new question since it's unrelated. Do you mean each exception? Or just when retries are exhausted? For the former, you can add a `RetryListener` to the `RetryTemplate` (create a template and pass it into the builder). For the latter, add a `Recoverer` to the builder.

Comment: I show my code in the main question. So, you mean the former way to do retry is RetryListener?

Comment: Since you are still using manual acks and doing a count yourself; you really don't need a retry interceptor - it will never be invoked since you always catch the exception. The interceptor is intended for use with AUTO ack mode.